# Incompatible pointer types initializing 'MainTableViewController'_strong with an expression of type 'PFQueryTableViewController'

Tags: ios, objective-c

First time using Parse. Not too sure what's going on here. Thanks for the help.

```
MainTableViewController *controller = [[PFQueryTableViewController alloc] init];

self.window.rootViewController = controller;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this line to work :

```
MainTableViewController *controller = [[PFQueryTableViewController alloc] init];
```

`PFQueryTableViewController` need to be a `subclass` of `MainTableViewController` which is probably not the case in your program.

Comment: Actually MainTableViewControll is a subclass of PFQueryTableViewController. I'm trying to follow this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=4SKugJO74BA#at=267

Comment: @STANGMMX did you import the header file?

Comment: Yeah I imported MainTableViewController.h into the AppDelegate.m

Comment: @STANGMMX : It's the other way around `MainTableViewController` need to be the super class and in your case it`s the sub class. You can assign a sub class to it's super class pointer, not the inverse.

Comment: @STANGMMX and also I've listen to the part of your Youtube and in the example the guy change the class name in both places.

Answer (score 0):

You can't initialize one class with another. Do this

```
MainTableViewController *controller = [[MainTableViewController alloc] init];
```

Comment: You can do it, if it is a subclass of the other one.